# variable in shell script newcatalog=`'$newcatalog' | sed 's/^-/\.\/-/'`

Tags: shell, unix, sed, ksh

I'm writing shell script:

```
read newcatalog
newcatalog=`'print -- $newcatalog | sed 's/^-/\.\/-/'`
cd "$newcatalog"
```

newcatalog this is the name of new catalog. Catalog name should support * ? and any options.

"-n" "-y" and other "-" in name of catalog work fine, but `*` doesn't work because

```
print -- $newcatalog
```

means

```
print -- * | sed 's/^-/\.\/-/'
```

and it sends to `sed` all files, but I want to send only `*`, like this:

```
print -- "*" | sed 's/^-/\.\/-/'
```

Comment: Can you escape the star? Like `print -- "\*"`?

Comment: I type from shell only *
but script should transform it in print -- "*"

Comment: I'm curious; what is the `print` command?  I know of `printf` and `echo`, but I don't have a plain `print` around.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Possibly from `ksh`, the Q is tagged both `bash` and `ksh`

Comment: @AlexZern: Which shell are you running the script in? `bash` or `ksh`?

Comment: @another.anon.coward: ah, yes; `ksh` does have `print`.  I'll undo the `bash` tag.  @Alex: your question title doesn't really match the question body.  You're missing the print from the outline command, etc.  Please update the title to match the question (or vice versa).  The title gives rise to another interesting line of analysis...most people don't have a command called `$newcatalog` (dollar and all) in their system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
newcatalog=`'print -- $newcatalog | sed 's/^-/\.\/-/'`
```

The first single quote inside the back ticks is an interloper and the shell should be diagnosing it to you.

```
newcatalog=`print -- $newcatalog | sed 's/^-/\.\/-/'`
```

(This leaves open the question of what are you actually executing.) In general, you should use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` ``.

```
newcatalog=$(print -- $newcatalog | sed 's/^-/\.\/-/')
```

If you're trying to avoid shell metacharacter expansion of `*`, then enclose the `$newcatalog` in double quotes:

```
newcatalog=$(print -- "$newcatalog" | sed 's/^-/\.\/-/')
```

That won't protect you completely.  If someone types: `$(rm -f *)` as the response to `read catalog`, you have deep problems even with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are working way too hard.  There is no need to invoke `sed` to do the replacement.  Just do:

```
test "${newcatalog#-}" = "$newcatalog" || newcatalog="./$newcatalog"
```